# click pdf link in web, how to preview instead of download?

Tags: pdf, web, hyperlink

I have my resume linked in my home page.

But I found when I host the pdf file on two different storage server, the default behavior when click on the link differs: one directly download the pdf file bug the other preview in a new tab.

the two links are as below:

http://data-10045577.file.myqcloud.com/doc/Zhao.Kai_ShanghaiUniv.pdf

http://7xocv2.dl1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/doc/Zhao.Kai_ShanghaiUniv.pdf

I have tested on **firefox** **chrome** **IE** that this is not a browser issue.

For some price issue I have to switch to the storage server of which the default behavior is downloading pdf file.

what settings should I have so that click the pdf link then preview instead of downlod?

Additionally, the storage server provide a configure option that can set the "http header", I know little about the web, so can setting a header work, if so, how to ?

---

I googled it and it seems the `content-disposition` argument in http header account for this. But I add `content-disposition='inline'`, doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if not the browser's issue, then the download one is added programmatically with headers, and the preview one is just putting your file in that folder on the server

Answer (score -1):

When you upload your files to the server for the first time, headers should properly set up to 'application/pdf'. Otherwise the browser will download it automatically.